# Front End Instance Hours reach limit super fast

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

I am terribly worried why my Google App Engine Application consumes super fast to its Front End Instance Hours. It's like 1 hour a day and then my Instance hour is reach its quota. Why I am experiencing this? I already read some articles regarding on this but it seems not solved. What is the right value of Idle Instance and Pending Latency? Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: Do you have push queue tasks?

Comment: Put both on automatic-automatic. I have an app with thousands of concurrent users all day and doesnt go over free quota.

Comment: Are you using Cloud SQL?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Actually I am new with GAE, what do u mean by that?

Comment: @AndyKing Yes, I'm using it.

Comment: cloud sql will generate a higher daily cost than the datastore, even when you dont use it. look at your daily report cost breakdown, identify the resoures that are going way over free quota. Cant do anything until you do that analysis.

Comment: @ZigMandel is cloud SQL connected to Front End Instance Hours? my daily report costs breakdown shows that it reach the Front End Instance Hours.

Comment: Instances that use Cloud SQL stay active for 12 hours after the last activity. (See the Cloud SQL FAQ [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq) ... search for "12"). You can manually stop an instance from the appspot.com instance page (click on the Instances link after selecting your instance). I have another SO question that was prompted by this issue ... I want to be able to stop an instance programmatically, but with no luck thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Application Dashboard, go to Application Settings

Under performance, check the Frontend Instance Class - An F1 will cost you one instance hour and hour, F2 will be 2, etc. You probably want it set to F1.

Set pending and idle instances to automatic-automatic - this means appengine will scale down your instances to the minimum required.

Assuming you have low volume and no particular memory or CPU requirements, these settings will allow you to run all day for free.

If you are running any backends (check under the Main -> Backends ), these will consume instance hours as well based on the type (B1, B2 etc). You can make these more cost effective by making them dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your instances are staying active for the default 12 hours after the last activity, which, for a Cloud SQL instance in a test environment, causes a lot of extra charges. I haven't yet determined how to programmatically shutdown instances, but you can change the default idle time before shutdown in the `appengine-web.xml` file (for Java), or the `app.yaml` file (for Python). I changed my ".xml" file so that my instances shut down after five minutes of inactivity by adding the following lines immediately before the final `</appengine-web-app>` line:

```
<basic-scaling>
  <idle-timeout>5m</idle-timeout>
</basic-scaling>
```

I found this information on the following page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

The Python information can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/